# Inverse of a one-to-one and continuous function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Show that if $f$ is continuous on an interval $[a,b]$ and one-to-one, then $f^{-1}$ is also continuous.

This is from Stephen Abbott's Understanding Analysis, Exercise 4.5.8.

I've read multiple proofs online but I can't seem to understand any.

What I've done so far:

$f$ is continuous, so it preserves connectedness and compactness which implies $f([a,b]) = [\alpha, \beta]$, for some $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$.

$f$ is monotone, so we can assume WLOG that $f$ is strictly increasing and so $f^{-1}$ is strictly increasing. We know $f^{-1}$ exists since $f$ is one-to-one.

I've also done a proof which does not require $f$ to be continuous and I've read that continuity of $f$ is not required. Why is this the case? I'm looking for a proof which uses the continuity of $f$.

One more thing I tried:

Lets say we have $(y_n) \to c$, for some $c \in [\alpha, \beta]$, where $(y_n) \subset [\alpha, \beta]$. Lets assume $f^{-1} (y_n)$ does converge and to some $f^{-1} (d) \in [a,b]$, where $f^{-1} (d) \neq f^{-1} (c)$. By continuity of $f$, we have $(y_n) \to d$, where $d \neq c$, by injectiveness. This is a contradiction to our hypothesis. The issue with this proof is that we must first show that $f^{-1} (y_n)$ does indeed converge.

Thank you.

Comment: Why is $f$ monotone?

Comment: Continuous+ injective implies strictly monotone

Comment: It's enough to show $f^{-1}(y_n) \to f^{-1}(c)$ when the $y_n \to c$ are monotone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closed interval $[a, b]$ is compact, so every sequence has a converging subsequence. In our case the limit point is the same for all such subsequences and equal to $f^{-1}(c)$ (just like in your reasoning).
Now it's easy to prove (f.i. by contradiction) that thus the whole sequence converges to this limit.

Comment: Being one 1-1 and monotone implies continuity. Just notice that the only discontinuity points would be jump discontinuities (by monotonicity), so the bijectivity would fail.

Comment: Although dropping the bijectivity assumtion you could think about constructing $f^{-1}$ defined only on the range of $f$, and it would be continuous too. Would you like to prove it?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, we're just interested in the range of f. I'm looking at what you said and thinking about it.

Comment: I mean consider f.i. $f(x) = x$ on $[0,1]$ and $f(x) = x+1$ on $(1,2]$. Then $f^{-1}$ would be a function defined only on $[0,1] \cup (2,3]$, but it would still be continuous. Are you interested in such cases as well?

Comment: No, not at the moment.

Comment: Since $f^{-1} (y_n) \in [a,b]$, we have that there is a subsequence $f^{-1} (y_{nk}) \to x'$. By continuity of $f$, we have that $(y_{nk}) \to f(x')$. Since we have $(y_n) \to c$, we have $c = f(x')$ and so $f^{-1} (y_{nk}) \to f^{-1} (c)$. Now I'm thinking on how to continue. Thank you for the hints.

Comment: Here is the complete proof, skip it if you want to think about it for yourself. We know that every subsequence of our sequence has a further subsequence that convergences to some numer $x$ (by compactness) same for every subsequence (by what I wrote earlier). So let's assume by contradiction, that our sequence doesn't converge to $x$. Then it has to have a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ and a number $t>0$ such that  $|x_{n_k}-x| > t$ for all $n_k$. But this subsequence has a further subsequence that converges to $x$ (by what I wrote at the beginning), thus the desired contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

I learned undergraduate analysis from Abbott as well, so I think the following argument should be something you can follow given you are in chapter 4 of Abbott. It just uses the fact that compact is the same as closed and bounded and the fact that continuous is equivalent to sequentially continuous. I cannot offer a remedy to your proof, but I can offer a proof that you might be able to understand (you mention you can't seem to understand any proofs that you have read) given your position in Abbott's book.

To show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous, we need to show that for any convergent sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ (converging to, say, $y$) in the domain of $f^{-1}$, we have that $f^{-1}(y_n)$ converges to $f^{-1}(y)$. This is by the sequential characterization of continuity that Abbott gives.

Since $f$ is continuous and its domain is compact, we have that the image of $f$ is also compact, hence closed. So, we have that $y = f(x)$ for some $x$, since $y$ is a limit point of the range of $f$.

Now, note that $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ can be written as $\big(f(x_n)\big)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ for some $x_n$ in the domain of $f$. So we are trying to show that $x_n$ converges to $x$.

So, we have a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $[a, b]$, which is a compact set. Thus, there is a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, who converges to, say, $x'$.

Now, by the continuity of $f$, we have that $f(x_{n_k})$ converges to $f(x')$. However, we have that $\big(f(x_{n_k})\big)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a subsequence of the convergent sequence $\big(f(x_n)\big)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, hence has the same limit. That is, we have that $f(x') = f(x)$. Lastly, we use injectivity of $f$ to conclude the result.

I would suggest reconciling your proof with this proof. Since your proof idea is to use injectivity to conclude strictly increasing, you could probably modify the above proof to say that $f(x') = f(x)$ immediately from the fact that $f$ is strictly increasing. Anyway, it would be a good exercise to try and modify the above proof to fit with your idea.

Comment: Yes, this answer goes in a good direction, toward the general form of the question, which manifestly does not use monotonicity. Namely, $f:X\to Y$ a continuous bijection from compact $X$ to Hausdorff $Y$ has a continuous inverse. Proof: for $U$ open in $X$, its complement $U^c$ is closed, so is compact. The continuous image $f(U^c)$ of a compact is compact in $Y$. In Hausdorff spaces, compact implies closed. Thus, the complement $f(U)$ is open. Done. :)

Comment: Thank you. The main issue though still remains, how do we show the whole sequence $f^{-1} (y_n)$ converges? I was able to do it using Jkbb's method.

Comment: @SonnyJordan: I see your concern. You can conclude that $f^{-1}(y_n)$ converges by proving the fact that a if subsequence of a monotonically increasing sequence converges, then the whole sequence must converge to the same limit as that of the subsequence.